# Neo4j blueprints index.remove() won't commit

Tags: clojure, neo4j, tinkerpop

I'm trying to create my own Clojure bindings of the tinkerpop.blueprints library, and I've come across a snag with what appears to be a commit failure. Currently I'm using Neo4j as the graph implementation. Here is the specific function that doesn't work:

```
(defn remove-from-index!
  ([index-name elm key]
    (remove-from-index!
      index-name elm key (property elm key)))
  ([index-name elm key val]
    (let [idx (index index-name)]
      (tx
        (-> idx
          (.remove (name key) val elm)))
      idx)))
```

to be used like this:

```
(remove-from-index! :users v1 :username)
(remove-from-index! :users v2 :username "foo")
```

It seems to be working properly, but when I query the index the vertex I tried to remove isn't removed. I tried to break it down piece by piece and determined that it actually *was* being removed, but as soon as `.commit` is called it rolls everything back.

other functions/macros involved:

```
(defn property
  [elm key]
  (-> elm (.getProperty (name key))))

(defmacro tx
  [& body]
  `(try
    (let [val# (do ~@body)]
      (.commit *g*)
      val#)
    (catch Exception e#
      (println (.getMessage e#))
      (.rollback *g*))))

(defn index
  ([^String nomen]
    (index (name nomen) "Vertex"))
  ([^String nomen ^String type]
    (-> *g*
      (.getIndex
        (name nomen)
        (Class/forName (str "com.tinkerpop.blueprints." type))))))
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your example usage seems to be missing the `elm` argument correct?  should be something like: `(remove-from-index! :users v :username)` where `v` is a Vertex.  is that right?

Comment: yes and I just edited the question. However, I dropped the database and, moving forward the problem hasn't resurfaced since. I'm not sure why. Probably the k/v in the index was something else than what I was trying to delete on. With Neo4j, you only need to supply the node to delete from an index, but going through the blueprints API you need both key and value in addition to the node in order to remove from the index. I'm guessing that was it, but I'm still unsure.